# Explaining this optical phenomenon

Tags: optics, everyday-life

Sometimes when you blow/direct a ring of smoke at a glass window(you can see both your reflections if you stand in front of it as well as the outside) the ring,after some time seems to pass through the pane into the outside surroundings.
How can i explain this? Does this have something do with the brightness of the object becoming comparable to the brightness of the objects outside and the brain perceiving this a s being a part of the outside ore this there a more mathematical/rigorous explanation for this?

Comment: I have not seen this, yet. Can you link to a video of this alleged phenomenon?

Comment: I have never come across this. Please provide link(s) or explain to us where and how did you see/hear about this?

Comment: there is a similar question in the book by resnick,halliday and krane

Comment: If you see something like this, it is a psychological phenomenon. The expected "distance" to an object in motion is determined partly by its angular subtense (apparent size) vs. time.

Comment: Please can you post the section of Halliday & Resnick which you are referring to?